# Proof: A subset C is closed iif $\forall x \notin C, \exists \varepsilon >0 / B(x, \varepsilon) \cap C = \varnothing$

Tags: general-topology

Let (X, d) be a metrical space, and C$\subset$X.

$\longrightarrow$) We know C is closed, therefore X$\setminus$C is open, applying the definition of an open set, we have that $\forall x\in X\setminus C, \exists \varepsilon$>0, so that the ball $B(x, \varepsilon)\cap X\setminus$ C. Therefore, because the ball is in X but not in C for each x, the intersection is empty.

I came up with this but I’m not sure it’s enough to prove $\longrightarrow$)?

Also, how would you prove $\longleftarrow$)?

Comment: Correct and this proves $(\Rightarrow)$. The other direction is pretty much identical, use the assumption to show that $X\setminus C$ is open. If you do things carefully, you could prove both implications at once.

Answer (score 1):

C is closed $ \iff $ X \C is open $ \iff \forall x \in$ X \C $ \exists \epsilon >0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon ) \subset $X \ C $\iff $ $ \forall x \notin C, \exists \epsilon >0$ such that $ B(x, \epsilon) \cap C = \emptyset$

Your proof is right.
I advise you to think always about the opposite implication.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof of $\implies$ is okay.

For proving $\impliedby$ observe that we can write the complement of $C$ as:$$X\setminus C=\bigcup_{x\notin C}B(x,\epsilon_x)$$where $\epsilon_x$ is positive with $B(x,\epsilon_x)\subseteq X\setminus C$  for every $x$.

So $X\setminus C$ is a union of open sets, hence is open itself.

That means that $C$ is closed.